# De/des + adj + noun (single - plural)

Tags: grammaire

I'm wondering about using '*des*' before noun. I know that if the adjective was before the noun we must use '*de*', but can anyone tell me why did we use '*des*' not '*de*' in this sentence :

> L'organisation travaille sur **des** grands domaines

Answer (score 1):

In fact, both are correct. Moreother **de** sound better in this case IMHO.

Comment: It depends on the end of the sentence : does it end after *"grands domaines"* (-> *de*)  or is there a subordinate clause (-> *des*)

Comment: @YohannV. I don't understand, what you mean exactly, could you elaborate and give an example ?

Comment: If you have a sentence like `L'organisation travaille sur de grands domaines.` you will prefer to use **de** because you don't add more informations. If you want to say more : `L'organisation travaille sur des grands domaines, qui bien que variés ont tous le même objectif.` you use **des** because this nominal group will be explained into the subordinate clause.